# Easiest way to remove parts of YouTube page

Tags: firefox, youtube

I'm using Firefox, and I've searched userscripts.org for a Greasemonkey script to block or remove certain sections that seem to just show up on my YouTube page.  **I mostly want to block the section called "Popular videos from Topic - Most popular",** which appears at the bottom of the page.

I have found no script that does this (though maybe I've just overlooked it), and can't seem to figure out whether or how to do this with AddBlockPlus, which I also have.  I didn't see an obvious setting in my user account for it, either.

I'd like to do this in a way that can adapt to future (inevitable) changes of YouTube so that I can keep this unwanted material off my page for the long haul, and do it without hoping that someone has made a script for me.

Comment: How about writing your own userscript, which you can update as required whenever YouTube changes its layout?

Comment: @Karan Sure, I'd be happy to.  I'm looking for help  on that here.  My guess is it is just one line of the script that would do that, but I've never written a script like that, and searching so far didn't reveal the trick to it.

Comment: Hopefully someone who's already created a similar script or has time to check YouTube's HTML can cook one up for you, or get you started at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a future-proof method isn't going to be easy. It's well known that YouTube constantly tweaks things and breaks the functionality of existing userscripts.

The only "future-proof" method, in my opinion,  is to learn how to do things oneself.

Here's what I do. I've installed the Stylish extension. You can read about it at userstyles.org and install it for Firefox from here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

With Stylish, you can make your own site-specific styles and modify them when needed without waiting for someone to do it for you. There's an official forum as well here: http://forum.userstyles.org/

Once you've installed Stylish, you need to get the appropriate code to hide something. Use the built-in `Inspector` feature of current Firefox versions. It can be accessed by positioning your mouse cursor over the relevant part of a page, right-clicking, and choosing `Inspect Element`. Try it! You won't break anything.

By using `Inspect Element`, I found that what needs to be hidden is `div.feed-item-dismissable.last`. So I make up this CSS rule: `div.feed-item-dismissable.last {display: none !important }`

To put things together, I make a new style called "YouTube" having the content given below:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document url-prefix(http://www.youtube.com/){
div.feed-item-dismissable.last {display: none !important; }
}
```

There are other ways to do what you need without the `Stylish` extension but this extension is just so useful for other things as well.

Edit: the code below works for both http and https:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document regexp("https?://www.youtube.com/") {
div.feed-item-dismissable.last {display: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: That's excellent!  Thank you, I've already used your code to great effect and get a super tip about Stylish to boot!

Answer (score 0):

Greasemonkey: https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4791-youtubedepopulator

The script is very simply, and shouldn't be hard to maintain yourself, if I ever quit updating it.